# Deriving the formula for the volume of a sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, volume

A circle $x^2 +y^2 =a^2$ is rotated about the $y$-axis to form a solid sphere of radius $a$.

How do you express this motion mathematically in such a way that it allows me to arrive at the formula for the volume of the sphere?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Sphere]

$$dV=(dr)(rd\theta)(rcos\theta d\phi)=[(r^{2}cos\theta dr) d\theta] d\phi$$

$$\rightarrow V=\int \int  \int [(r^{2}cos\theta dr) d\theta] d\phi$$

So I guess if you integrate w.r.t dr,d$\theta$ you get a disk.Now to 'rotate' this disk integrate the result w.r.t d$\phi$

**Note:** Using this method one can find that there are 6 ways to do this integration to find out the volume.(each way is unique and interesting)

Comment: When making a transverse cut along the sphere diameter, obtain the area of the circle with radius "a". If we rotate around the axis y, this area, we obtain the initial sphere. How to express this mathematically? Much like taking a coin and turn it vertically on the floor.

Comment: How did you make this quality picture?

Comment: @HermesRozsaIglesias:That's what I did.I guess you are familiar with calculus.If so then Try integrating $r^{2}cos\theta$ w.r.t. $dr$ and then integrate the result w.r.t. $d\theta$.You will get a disk.Now integrate it w.r.t. $d\phi$ to get the volume of a sphere.Look at the picture and try interpretating what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Each point $(\rho,z)$ in the meridian half-plane $M:=\{(\rho,z)\>|\>\rho\geq0,\ z\in{\mathbb R}\}$ produces under rotation around the $z$-axis a circle
$$\phi\mapsto(x,y,z):=(\rho\cos\phi,\rho\sin\phi, z)\ ,$$
and an area element ${\rm d}A={\rm d}(\rho,z)$ in $M$ produces a ring-shaped body of volume
$${\rm d}V=2\pi\rho\ {\rm d}A=2\pi \rho\ {\rm d}(\rho,z)\ .$$
In order to obtain a solid sphere $B_a$ of radius $a>0$ we have to rotate the half circle $$H:=\{(\rho,z)\>|\> 0\leq\rho\leq a,\ |z|\leq\sqrt{a^2-\rho^2}\}$$
around the $z$-axis. In this way we get
$${\rm vol}(B_a)=\int_{B_a}{\rm d}V=2\pi\int\nolimits_{H}\rho\ {\rm d}(\rho,z)=2\pi\int_0^a \rho\ \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-\rho^2}}^\sqrt{a^2-\rho^2}dz\ d\rho=\ldots={4\pi\over3}a^3\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat way to do it using the divergence theorem, see exercise II-60,chapter-1, Div, Curl , Grad and all that problem II-26. We have the formula:

$$ \frac13 \int_{S} \hat{n} \cdot \vec{r}dS = V$$

Where $\vec{r}$ is a position vector to a point on the surface, $\hat{n}$ is surface normal

The above equation can be verified via divergence theorem.

**Calculating the volume:**

For our calculations , we will consider spherical coordinates with the $\hat{r}$ unit vector and center our origin at the Center of sphere of radius R. This leads to:

$$ V = \frac13 \int_S \hat{r} \cdot R \hat{r} dS= \frac{R}{3} \int dS= \frac43 \pi R^3 $$

QED

Answer (score 0):

Every point of the half-circle follows a trajectory of length $2\pi x$. If you integrate over that half-circle,

$$\int_{-r}^r\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}2\pi x\,dx\,dy=\int_{-r}^r\pi(r^2-y^2)\,dy=2\pi\left(r^3-\dfrac{r^3}3\right).$$